# How to reference variable in python html email?

Tags: python, html, email, flask, gmail

I am trying to send an email with python and i have a variable ("string") from my flask route which i would like to reference in my email html.

```
@app.route('/edit', methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit():
...
    s_list = S.query.all()
    strings = '\n'.join([str(s) for s in s_list])
    
        
    global string
    string = str(strings)
    print(string)
```

However, nothing appears in the variable part when the email is sent. I tried to print it on terminal and could see the results.

Can anyone let me know what am i doing wrongly please?

```
  message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
  message["Subject"] = "Thank you."
  message["From"] = sender_email
  message["To"] = user_mail

  # Write the plain text part
  text = "Thank you for your submission! " + string

  # write the HTML part
  html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you for your submission! <br>
       """ + string + """

        <br></br>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(string=string)

  # convert both parts to MIMEText objects and add them to the MIMEMultipart message
  part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
  part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
  message.attach(part1)
  message.attach(part2)
```

Comment: But... this works. Not exactly how you would expect it to work, but works - you add your variable into there (although not with format, just the `+string+` works). Could you check if your `string` actually contains anything inside it?

Comment: thanks!!! my "string" is actually an output from database query.  so this is how i derived it from one of my routes (updated above)

Comment: email code same in edit function  ?

Comment: As I said, it works for me. where is the email sending located? Maybe you shadow the global `string` with local `string` or overwrite it somewhere else? In general, you shouldn't use globals for such things

Comment: thank you! you're right! i defined string somewhere else instead of using global and it worked! :)